# Getting PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: java, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

I have a bit complex configuration of my Java based Web application.
My application is Running on Tomcat 8.5 and I have integrated my Tomcat with IIS. In my application we have a functionality to send the report to specifc mail ID and it is scheduled Job which runs in the background. Everything works fine untill I configure my IIS with SSL. The report failed to send with below exception **Although I have imported the certificate in Java's Keystore (cacerts) it is the same certificate which I configured in IIS.**

PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

```
String addr= "https://IISSITE/report/id";
HttpsURLconnection  connection= (HttpsURLConnection) addr.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "SEC_TOKEN=" + _sessionInfo.getToken());
connection.setReadTimeout(_connectionTimeout * MILLISECONDS);
connection.connect();
```

Comment: Whenever Java attempts to connect to another application over SSL, it will only be able to connect to that application if it can trust it. The way trust is handled in the Java world is that you have a keystore (typically $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts), also known as the trust store. Make sure you have imported the public certificate of the target instance into the truststore.Check if your Anti Virus tool has "SSL Scanning" blocking SSL/TLS. If it does, disable this feature or set exceptions for the target addresses.

Comment: if connecting to a mail server, such as Exchange, ensure authentication allows plain text. Verify that the target server is configured to serve SSL correctly. If all else fails, your truststore might be out of date. Upgrade Java to the latest version supported by your application.